# error compiling java -use source 5

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin, flume

please forgive me if this is a silly question but i am trying to compile some java code that I found at http://thisdataguy.com/2014/02/07/how-to-build-a-full-flume-interceptor-by-a-non-java-developer/

I am very new to java programming and when I run the code I get the error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.apache.flume:eventTweaker:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/target (included: [**], excluded:    [])
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/src/main/java/com/example/flume/interceptors   /eventTweaker.java:[18,3] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Override

/home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/src/main/java/com/example/flume/interceptors/eventTweaker.java:[24,7] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
Map<String, String> headers = event.getHeaders();

/home/kwincott/jars/tweaker/src/main/java/com/example/flume/interceptors/eventTweaker.java:[46,20] for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
for (Event event:events) {


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 20 16:26:17 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `annotations are not supported in -source 1.3` and `generics are not supported in -source 1.3` and `for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3`. There's your problem, these are not supported. `use -source 5 or higher`

Comment: how would I go about that? like I said in the original post I am very new to java as a programming language.

Comment: Maybe you are using an outdated version of JDK or maven?

Comment: Download and try with newer java version jdk6, 7 or 8 and Maven 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: Please use Maven 3.X at least and not [Maven 2.X anymore](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Maven's compiler plugin cares nothing for what Java version you actually use. The error message is prompting you to set some configuration in your `pom.xml`:

- [Maven Compiler plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)
- Also helpful: [What is the difference between using javac and javax.tools.JavaCompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216774/what-is-the-difference-between-using-javac-and-javax-tools-javacompiler#20218834)

Answer (score -3):

The build failure report pretty much says everything:

```
[18,3] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Override

[24,7] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
Map<String, String> headers = event.getHeaders();

[46,20] for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
for (Event event:events) {
```

**(use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)**

You are probably using an outdated version of JDK (6 or up) and/or Maven (3.x or up). Update to the newest JDK and Maven version and the error should be gone.

But, as it says in the INFO section at the end of your build report, `for more information, run Maven with the -e switch`. This will help you for debugging issues in the future.

Comment: Im using java6 (open-jdk6) and maven 2

Comment: @KevinWincott Sorry, 3 or up, not 2 or up.

Comment: Update to Maven 3 as soon as possible...[cause Maven 2 is EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).